# Optimizing DROP TABLE on a huge InnoDB table

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an innodb table with over 140 million rows taking 26GB. I would like to drop this table however this is taking way too long, probably days. How can I speed up this query?

processor: Intel® Xeon® E3-1220 4 Cores x 3.1 GHz (3.4 Turbo Boost)
ram: 12 GB DDR3 ECC

Comment: What is your `innodb_file_per_table` setting?  See this related article  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/03/performance-problem-with-innodb-and-drop-table/

Comment: @MikeBrant innodb_file_per_table is off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem, who would've thought it was because of integrity checks:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53515/drop-table-on-a-huge-innodb-table/

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to check referential integrity while deleting records, use

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name
```

More in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html).

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on your `innodb_file_per_table` setting. You may find [Performance problem with Innodb and DROP TABLE](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/02/03/performance-problem-with-innodb-and-drop-table/) relevant:

> If you’re not using innodb_file_per_table you’re not affected because
>   in this case tablespace does not need to be dropped so pages from
>   Buffer pool LRU do not need to be discarded. The raw performance of
>   dropping tables I measured on the test server was 10 times better with
>   single tablespace, though this will vary a lot depending on buffer
>   pool size. MyISAM tables creating/dropping was several times faster
>   still.

Also check

## [Slow DROP TABLE](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/06/16/slow-drop-table/)